# Change camera from rectangle to square by center

Tags: camera

Is there a way to change axis of scaling camera?
I have a rectangular render, but need to get identical square render. I simply need to cut off the left and right side of the camera view, but after changing camera settings, i get extra view space above and below my desired picture.
I am not interested in zoom-related solutions, since it and Focal Lengh would definitely differ from the original rectangular render.

Thank you in advance for your time!

[image: rectangular camera view]
[image: changed to square]
[image: added undesired space above and below]
[image: how can i change camera format by center?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The camera property Sensor Size is a measurement in the *largest* camera dimension. Therefore, to keep the same scaling, if you change the largest dimension (in this case, reducing from 1920 to 1080 leads to a reduction to 56.25%) to match the smaller dimension (eg, 1080) you simply need to adjust the Sensor Size to match te reduction in the maximum dimension.

Therefore, for default render dimensions of 1920x1080 changed to square 1080x1080, the largest dimension is reduced to 56.25% of its original size (1080/1920 = 0.5625) - so to keep the same scaling the Sensor Size of 32 should be similarly reduced as 0.5625 x 32 = 18.

[image: rescaled]

Answer (score 1):

Best way for me: set your output size to the required square dimensions. Then adapt the camera's focal length to get the required crop *without changing the camera position*.

Changing the focal length will **not** change the perspective, so the cube (and other objects) will still look the same (but the apparent size will change).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others are trying to find this setting in Blender 2.83: it is on the `Output Properties` tab of the Scene:

[image]

With this setting I was able to set the camera shape to a square.