# How to increase visible area of a camera without side effects?

Tags: camera

I would like to increase visible area of my perspective camera, so that more content could fit in. I tried increasing FOV, but high FOV values made my image bend at the vertical edges. It seems that higher resolution values give me the desired result, but I want to keep default 1920x1080.

[image]

Is it posible?

Comment: Just move the camera back.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the visible area of theh camera without actually moving the camera (which would change the view through the camera) you can simply adjust the Camera 'Sensor Size' in the camera properties. See related answer for [Change camera from rectangle to square by center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105805/29586)

Answer (score -3):

Press Shift + F to enter "Fly Mode", use the WASD keys to move the camera around, press Enter to accept the changed.

Comment: Can you please explain how this actually solves the problem in the question?

Comment: It allows you to move the camera around and position the object so you can see more of it.

Comment: He said he wanted to keep the sensor size at 1920 x 1080 so the only logic step would be to move the camera.